# How can I use C++ boost geometry to create ring (donut) from two polgons?

Tags: c++, boost, geometry, boost-geometry

I am trying to calculate the differences between 2 polygons (in fact, rectilinear shapes for simplicity). For example, shape1 has point list {0 0, 100, 0, 100 100, 0 100} and shape2 has point list {25 25, 75 25, 75 75, 25 75}.
So by concept, I expect "shape1 - shape2" will provide me with 4 rectangular boxes, which can make a ring or donut shape.  I don't know how to achieve that, but I found "boost" library online and tried it like this:

[image]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp>

#include <boost/foreach.hpp>


int main()
{
    typedef boost::geometry::model::polygon<boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double> > polygon;

    polygon green, blue;

    boost::geometry::read_wkt( "POLYGON((0 0 100 0 100 100 0 100))", green);

    boost::geometry::read_wkt( "POLYGON((25 25 75 22 75 75 25 75))", blue);

    std::list<polygon> output;
    boost::geometry::difference(green, blue, output);

    int i = 0;
    std::cout << "green - blue:" << std::endl;
    BOOST_FOREACH(polygon const& p, output)
    {
        std::cout << i++ << ": " << boost::geometry::area(p) << std::endl;
    }


    output.clear();
    boost::geometry::difference(blue, green, output);

    i = 0;
    std::cout << "blue - green:" << std::endl;
    BOOST_FOREACH(polygon const& p, output)
    {
        std::cout << i++ << ": " << boost::geometry::area(p) << std::endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

However, nothing was printed out ... My plan was to figure out a way to convert the output results to rectangular boxes {0 0 100 0 100 25 0 25} {0 75 100 75 100 100 0 100} {0 25 25 25 25 75 0 75}  and {75 25 100 25 100 75 75 75},but I feel frustrated that the above code not print out anything at all.

Could anyone give me some guidance? 
I have attached a picture showing what I want to do. In fact, I have already had all the point coordinates to represent this donut, so maybe I can skip "difference() function" ?  If this is the case, the difficult part will be to convert the donut into rectangular segments. (Let us assume all polygons here are rectilinear shapes.)
Thanks.

Comment: "If this is the case, the difficult part will be to convert the donut into rectangular segments" - Polygons (OGC definition) can have holes anyways, see [my second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47690552/85371)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47690447/85371) will end your frustration/confusion, this answer will make you more productive :)

And, yes, you can skip the difference function:

```
bg::read_wkt("POLYGON((0 0 0 100 100 100 100 0 0 0) (25 25 75 22 75 75 25 75 25 25))", donut);
```

This specifies the inner ring (in reverse orientation!).

Result:

[image]

Generated by this program:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/12a8b5e422330d3c)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

namespace bg = boost::geometry; 

int main() {
    typedef bg::model::d2::point_xy<double> point;
    typedef bg::model::polygon<point> polygon;

    polygon donut;
    bg::read_wkt("POLYGON((0 0 0 100 100 100 100 0 0 0) (25 25 75 22 75 75 25 75 25 25))", donut);

    std::ofstream svg("output.svg");
    boost::geometry::svg_mapper<point> mapper(svg, 400, 400);
    mapper.add(donut);

    mapper.map(donut, "fill-opacity:0.5;fill:rgb(0,0,153);stroke:rgb(0,0,200);stroke-width:2");
}
```

Comment: How to add the inner rings (holes) incrementally? I mean one ring at a time. Assuming ring is a vector of point in clockwise direction.

Comment: @qqqqq That would be... the code in the question. Alternatively, you can add inner rings: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/16777ee162b6b009 note that the standard `Ring` model already is basically that vector: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e5c2bca33fcb1d47

Answer (score 1):

Your starting polygons do not have the required orientation. You can find this out for yourself with `is_valid`. Conveniently, you can use `correct` to fix the most common problems with your input data:

```
std::string reason;
if (!bg::is_valid(geometry, reason))
{
    std::cout << "Correcting " << bg::wkt(geometry) << " to ";
    bg::correct(geometry);
    std::cout << bg::wkt(geometry) << "\n";

    if (!bg::is_valid(geometry, reason))
        std::cout << "UNCORRECTIBLE: " << reason << "\n";
}
```

When you do, you will find:

```
Correcting POLYGON((0 0,100 0,100 100,0 100,0 0)) to POLYGON((0 0,0 100,100 100,100 0,0 0))
Correcting POLYGON((25 25,75 22,75 75,25 75,25 25)) to POLYGON((25 25,25 75,75 75,75 22,25 25))
```

Now, when you get the difference, you will get the expected outcome:

```
auto do_diff = [](std::string caption, auto const& a, auto const& b) {
    multi output;
    bg::difference(a, b, output);

    std::cout << caption << bg::wkt(output) << std::endl;
};

do_diff("green - blue:", green, blue);
do_diff("blue - green:", blue, green);
```

### Full Demo

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f1a870ee882bf3dc)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/multi_polygon.hpp>

#include <boost/foreach.hpp>

namespace bg = boost::geometry; 

int main() {
    typedef bg::model::d2::point_xy<double> point;
    typedef bg::model::polygon<point> polygon;
    typedef bg::model::multi_polygon<polygon> multi;

    polygon green, blue;

    bg::read_wkt("POLYGON((0 0 100 0 100 100 0 100))", green);
    bg::read_wkt("POLYGON((25 25 75 22 75 75 25 75))", blue);

    auto test = [](polygon& geometry) {
        std::string reason;
        if (!bg::is_valid(geometry, reason))
        {
            std::cout << "Correcting " << bg::wkt(geometry) << " to ";
            bg::correct(geometry);
            std::cout << bg::wkt(geometry) << "\n";

            if (!bg::is_valid(geometry, reason))
                std::cout << "UNCORRECTIBLE: " << reason << "\n";
        }
    };

    test(green);
    test(blue);

    auto do_diff = [](std::string caption, polygon const& a, polygon const& b) {
        multi output;
        bg::difference(a, b, output);

        std::cout << caption << bg::wkt(output) << std::endl;
    };

    do_diff("green - blue:", green, blue);
    do_diff("blue - green:", blue, green);

    {
        std::ofstream svg("output.svg");
        boost::geometry::svg_mapper<point> mapper(svg, 400, 400);
        mapper.add(blue);
        mapper.add(green);

        mapper.map(blue, "fill-opacity:0.5;fill:rgb(0,0,153);stroke:rgb(0,0,200);stroke-width:2");
        mapper.map(green, "fill-opacity:0.5;fill:rgb(0,153,0);stroke:rgb(0,200,0);stroke-width:2");
    }
}
```

Prints

```
Correcting POLYGON((0 0,100 0,100 100,0 100,0 0)) to POLYGON((0 0,0 100,100 100,100 0,0 0))
Correcting POLYGON((25 25,75 22,75 75,25 75,25 25)) to POLYGON((25 25,25 75,75 75,75 22,25 25))
green - blue:MULTIPOLYGON(((0 0,0 100,100 100,100 0,0 0),(25 25,75 22,75 75,25 75,25 25)))
blue - green:MULTIPOLYGON()
```

And writes the svg for:

[image]

Comment: May I ask one more thing?  Is there an existing method in boost geometry that allows me to generate rectangular segments from a rectilinear donut?  This example is a square shape,  but in general, the shape of the recilinear donut might look like an "L" or "T" shape.

Comment: I think that would merit a separate question. I don't readily have an answer to that